# Do i have to define all function in mainActivity.java

Tags: java, android, android-layout

When I made an new activity `.xml` file in android studio, it created a corresponding `.java` file.

I set an onClick method call from new activity, but it still is looking for that method in `mainActivity.java`.

I want to define activities method in corrosopnding `.java` file and link .xml with .java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, you are trying to set an action onClick() for a button or some other view, however when you click it nothing happens. Is that right? It seems to me like your activity is tied to the wrong .xml file. Double check that in your .java files have the correct layout defined in setContentView();

For example...

In MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // pay attention to this

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button); // or else it won't know where to find the button in the layout
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main2Activity.class);
            tartActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

In Main2Activity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2); // pay attention to this too


}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I guess i will have to go by the basics first. :)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you create a new activity on Android it will not come to life unless you tell it to by code. Now, if you look into your manifest file you will be able to see which one is the activity that is started with the program, the initial is the MainActivity.java file(It does not have to be named MainActivity but it is the default in Android)

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

If you look into your manifest file after you have added the second activity you will see a new `<activity>` tag with the name of the second activity that you added right before the end of the application tag:

```
<activity
  android:name=".Main2Activity"
  android:label="@string/title_activity_main2"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
</activity>
```

This means that your activities are properly registered on your manifest file(as they should)

In order for you to use it you would require something to call it, like a button click that activates an `Intent` just like Michael said above me. Try to go through the basic Android tutorial to see this happening and try and implement it yourself. Every view that you have in android corresponds to an activity file(for the most part, they can be fragments as well but that is a topic for another day) and most of the code corresponding the activity events will definitely require you to code your logic inside the activity file. Think of the java file as the controller, the xml layouts as the view, your controller file manipulates the view.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. It helped me a great deal to understand thing. What i am trying to do is to bind an activity to java file so when ever i call a function, it looks in corresponding java file (not main activity).

Comment: Glad I could help, don't get discouraged and keep trying to make sense of the Android documentation and the rest of the tutorials. They can be quite complex to understand but are definitely worth the headache. As for the binding of the function, try doing something like what it is done in the tutorial or what Michael said :) can't go wrong with that one! cheers.